# How to recover Password From SH1 String

Tags: asp.net, authentication

```
 string pass = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "SHA1");
```

I use above function to make SH1 string password.So how i can do opposite of that.How I can make SH1 String to password.Please reply soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. When you hash data with SHA1 (or MD5 or whatever) you lose information, the original string can't be recovered.

The only sensible thing you can do with a hash is to compare it with the result of hashing of another string to determine if the entered password is correct:

```
bool passwordMaches = (pass ==
    FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(enteredPassword, "SHA1"));
```